# MVC5 how do I display a loading bar/spinning circle/loader when a function is running

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, loading

I'm using a function in MVC5/C# to send emails. However the function does take a while to run before it redirects the user to a page that says "successfully sent". So I want to display a loading window/bar to tell the user to wait till the function is done. But I'm confused as to how to implement this as most articles/questions I looked at only involves implementing this while loading a page instead of running a function.Any help or code example is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: This is the code I'm using to send emails

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> sendEmails()
{ 
  var body = "Mail Content";
  var message = new MailMessage();
  message.To.Add(new MailAddress("example.mail@companydomain.com"));  // replace with valid value 
  message.From = new MailAddress("from.mail@companydomain.com");  // replace with valid value
  message.Subject = "Mail Subject";
  message.Body = body;
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;

  using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
       {
           var credential = new NetworkCredential
           {
               UserName = "from.mail@companydomain.com",  // replace with valid value
               Password = "password"  // replace with valid value
           };
           smtp.Credentials = credential;
           smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
           smtp.Port = 587;
           smtp.EnableSsl = true;
           await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);

        }
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Can you show the function you're running?

Comment: Hi I've edited the code in

Answer (score 2):

If it is ajax call then you can follow below approch.This will show full screen overlay with spinner.

Use below JQuery on _Layout view so that this works for all ajax call.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loading").show();
 });
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
     $("#loading").hide();
 });
```

Loading Div markup

```
<div id="loading" class="loading" style="display:none"></div>
```

and CSS

```
/***loading screen***/
/* Absolute Center Spinner */
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow:show;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Transparent Overlay */
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/* :not(:required) hides these rules from IE9 and below */
.loading:not(:required) {
  /* hide "loading..." text */
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.loading:not(:required):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
}

/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/***loading end****/
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Pratham looks to be about what you want. You're not far off from turning that into Ajax, which means instead of redirecting you can show a green success message on the same page. You'll want to look into [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Then instead of a redirect the function you posted above would instead return something like

```
new JsonResult{
  Data = new object{status = "Success"}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Ajax function, assuming you are using one to call the endpoint that sends the email, call the showLoading() function. You will have to implement this one, with a bootstrap modal or something similar. Then, in your success or error of your ajax call, just call your hideLoading function, that again, you will have to implement.